# Sum Values in Column based on indexes of other columns and then assigning that value to each row

Tags: r, database, data-manipulation, data-management

I am currently dealing with a data set that has shots taken on a basketball court. I currently have the shot count for each individual, but I would get the shot count per team. Rather than having to do all of the code I did for each individual, I would prefer to retrieve it from these columns.

Example of data set

```
Player_ID    Team           Shot_Count      Date
1          "Red"            14           12/15/12
2          "Blue"           12           2/14/12
3          "Red"            23           12/15/12
4          "Blue"           15           3/15/12
2          "Blue"           14           5/2/12
3          "Red"            23           11/11/12
```

The desired output:

```
Player_ID    Team           Shot_Count      Date       Team_Count
1          "Red"            14           12/15/12          37
2          "Blue"           12           2/14/12           27
3          "Red"            23           12/15/12          37
4          "Blue"           15           3/15/12           27
2          "Blue"           14           5/2/12            27
3          "Red"            23           11/11/12          37
```

The issue I am having is how to only count a player's Shot_Count a single time, because it is repeated throughout the data set. Also keep in mind, these are not the only variables in the dataset (i.e. for any joins), they are just the relevant ones.

I included the dates because I would also like to find these values "per game" where the date would be used as an identifier for a game. It is essentially the same concept, I will want the count the team's shot count in the game for that unique date and then assign it to row with that date in a new column.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome here. Please include your own approach to the problem, the result from your research and where you got stuck. This is not a coding service but we are glad to help you when you hit a brickwall somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'Team', get the `sum` of 'Shot_Count' where the 'Player_ID' is unique (or not duplicated)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  mutate(Team_Count = sum(Shot_Count[!duplicated(Player_ID)]))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups: Team [2]
#  Player_ID Team  Shot_Count Date     Team_Count
#      <int> <chr>      <int> <chr>         <int>
#1         1 Red           14 12/15/12         37
#2         2 Blue          12 2/14/12          27
#3         3 Red           23 12/15/12         37
#4         4 Blue          15 3/15/12          27
#5         2 Blue          14 5/2/12           27
#6         3 Red           23 11/11/12         37
```